# Overloading in subclass not working

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding, overloading

I have he following scenario:

```
public abstract class Value<T> {
    public void Value add(Value v) {
       // Statements
    }
}

public class IntValue extends Value<String> {
    public void IntValue add(IntValue v) {
       // Statements
    }
}
```

And in another part of the code:

```
public void exec(Value a, Value b) {
     a.add(b);
}
```

My question is, why, knowing that a and b are instances of IntValue, the code executed is from their super class.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Because the method in `IntValue` is **not** an override of the method in `Value`; it has different argument types.  And even if it was, overload selection is performed on the static types of arguments, not on the dynamic runtime types.

Comment: Because those method signatures are different, and you're calling the superclass method.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you really understood what i meant to do. If you are kind enough to post it as a answer i will mark it a the correct one. Thanks to all of you folks!

Answer (score 2):

You have an example of [method overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) (when you meant to use [overriding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)). This is a good example of why you should use the [`@Override`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation. Also (I presume) your generic `Value` class should be generic on `T`

```
public abstract class Value<T> {
  public void Value<T> add(Value<T> v) {
   // Statements
  }
}
```

Adding the annotation you would get a compile error,

```
public class IntValue extends Value<Integer> {
  @Override
  public void IntValue add(IntValue v) {
   // Statements
  }
}
```